# Class define custom sort order

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a lot of simple classes that need to be sorted. Example:

```
IEnumerable<Sortsample> OutputList = List.OrderBy(x => x);
```

All of there classes only need to be sorted by a defined property like this:

```
class Sortsample
{     
    [SortAttribute] //Item should be sorted by Date
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there something like a `[SortAttribute]` (or a similar easy way) or do i have to implemet `CompareTo` for each class?

Comment: you have to write a generic extension method

Comment: why not list.OrderBy(x => x.Date); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attribute is not a very good match for this, because you run into several problems:

- You can't specify how each individual property should be compared, if there is a choice, because attributes need to work at compile time and don't allow complicated objects like an `IComparer` to be passed. You have to rely on the default. For strings, you could work around this by using `StringComparison`, which is an enum and can be passed to an attribute.
- Processing attributes means using reflection and generic code. This is fairly easy if you don't care a lot about performance and quite hard if you do. It also introduces more "magic" that may make the code harder to understand for maintainers.
- Because your class will not implement `IComparable`, no code that relies on `IComparable` for ordering can use your custom ordering out of the box. You could, in theory, implement `IComparable` through a base class, but this doesn't work if you need to integrate with an existing object hierarchy.
- You're stuck with one particular way to order the items. This is OK if you consider this the "default" order and have some way of doing a custom comparison if necessary.

In general, explicitly passing a method to `.OrderBy()` or implementing `IComparable<T>`  if there's only one reasonable way to order are better choices. But with all that said: yes, you *can* make it so that you can have instances ordered based on an attribute in the class, by generating an `IComparer` on demand.

Define a simple attribute first:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
class SortKeyAttribute : Attribute { }
```

To be used like this, for example:

```
class SortSample {
    [SortKey]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And let's imagine we had an extension method `.OrderByKey()` which would order instances for us by the property to which `[SortKey]` was applied, then we could call it like so:

```
IEnumerable<SortSample> outputList = list.OrderByKey();
```

And one possible implementation of that method follows:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderByKey<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence) {
        return sequence.OrderBy(x => x, getKeyComparer<T>());
    }

    static IComparer<T> createComparer<T, TKey>(PropertyInfo key) {
        Func<T, TKey> keySelector = x => (TKey) key.GetValue(x);
        var keyComparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
        return Comparer<T>.Create(
            (x, y) => keyComparer.Compare(keySelector(x), keySelector(y))
        );
    }

    static IComparer<T> getKeyComparer<T>() {
        List<PropertyInfo> sortKeyProperties = (
            from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
            let a = (SortKeyAttribute) p
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SortKeyAttribute))
                .FirstOrDefault()
            where a != null
            select p
        ).ToList();
        if (sortKeyProperties.Count == 0) {
            // with no [SortKey], fall back to the default comparer
            return Comparer<T>.Default;
        }
        if (sortKeyProperties.Count > 1) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                $"Multiple sort keys specified for class '{typeof(T).FullName}'."
            );
        }
        PropertyInfo sortKeyProperty = sortKeyProperties[0];
        MethodInfo createComparerMethodInfo = typeof(EnumerableExtensions)
            .GetMethod("createComparer", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
        ;
        return (IComparer<T>) createComparerMethodInfo
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), sortKeyProperty.PropertyType)
            .Invoke(null, new[] { sortKeyProperty })
        ;
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- Reflection is used to create the `IComparer` instance based on the property type's `Comparer.Default`. This is fairly slow, but we can expect that sorting will mostly spend time in `IComparer.CompareTo`, and that isn't implemented through reflection. Nevertheless, this code can be optimized using standard methods for optimizing reflection (`Reflection.Emit`, expression trees, caching generated instances in static dictionaries).
- It's possible (but not very easy) to extend this code to handle multiple `SortKey` properties correctly, so you could write `[SortKey(1)]` for example.
- For strings, where you may want a choice of comparison, you could introduce a `StringComparison` parameter. This doesn't extend to other types.
- You could expose `getKeyComparer` through a public interface so you can use methods that take an `IComparer<T>` (but if you do this a lot, you may as well implement `IComparable<T>`).

To reiterate, this may look clever, and it answers your question, but in production code I wouldn't go with attributes for sorting, for the reasons I mentioned at the start. The drawbacks outweigh the benefits, in my opinion, and implementing `IComparable` directly is probably a better choice, even if it means more code (and if that's an issue, you can look at various ways to generate code, like with T4 templates).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest implementing `IComparable<Sortsample>`:

```
  class Sortsample: IComparable<Sortsample> {
    public DateTime Date {
      get; set;
    }
    public string Name {
      get; set;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Sortsample other) {
      // if "other" is, in fact, "this" 
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        return 0;
      else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, other)) 
        return 1; // let's consider that "this" (not null) > null

      // other is not this, and other is not null
      return Date.CompareTo(other.Date);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't see how checking reference equality would sort. You would need to return -1 or 0 or 1 based on `Date` comparisons.

Comment: @Crowcoder - that's the standard pattern. Check if `this` and `other` reference the same thing, if so they're equal (sorted into the same spot) => `0`. Else, check if `other` is a NullReference. Nulls are always less than anything, so `this` comes after => `1`. Now that we know that `this` and `other` are different and not null, do the "real" comparison, i.e. compare the dates.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko, I disagree. Reference equality makes no difference if you want to sort your class instances by a date property. And then to have to compare dates afterwards anyway? I would like to see how you complete the implementation of the sort and a reference to the "standard pattern".

Comment: That's better but won't work with structs and does not satisfy requirement to not have to implement a comparer for each Type.

Comment: @Crowcoder - I'm not sure I follow your objection. If `Sortsample` was a `struct`, then `ReferenceEquals` would still "work" (but always return false). But since it's a `class`, there could be two variables, pointing to the same instance. In that case, why bother with any comparing logic? If they're the same, sort them in the same place (`0`). Also, `other` could be `null` so you need to check that anyway. If you just say `return Date.CompareTo(other.Date);` without checking if `other` is null, you'll get an Exception. So this is the minimal complete code necessary. Where do you see a problem?

Comment: (Well, checking `ReferenceEquals(this, other)` is not *necessary*, but a very cheap optimization)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109669/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-corak).